# How can I use pm2 to deploy nodejs app in railway.app?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have been trying to use pm2 to push my REST API into production in https://railway.app. But everytime I am trying to use pm2 in the start script the app is crashing, whereas if I am using "node index.js" the app seems to be working fine

With pm2

[image]

Without pm2

[image]